# "Likes" get lost

Tags: facebook, social-media, like, share-this

From time to time our website loses as lot of likes
for example two days ago the number of like was more than 1k
then  all of a sudden it became 480

Also  strange is that
this query 
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22printdirect.ru/index.php%22

Has 480 total_count

But this link   http://graph.facebook.com/http://printdirect.ru/index.php
returns "shares": 1912

What can be the reason of such a loss?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook "Likes" are linked to unique URL strings. In your case, your Likes are being split between two URLs:

```
http://printdirect.ru/index.php
printdirect.ru/index.php
```

You can test this by using each URL in your original query. To solve the problem, you need to make sure you always specify the same URL when using Like buttons that refer to the same page.

Unfortunately, there is no way to consolidate the Likes. You'll just have to choose one over the other.